Issues with Table Formatting and Inconsistent Headings in PDF Output using knitr::kable
I'm having trouble with table formatting when knitting my RMarkdown document to PDF. I have defined a function for formatting tables, but I'm encountering issues with inconsistent headings (see screenshot).
Here’s the function I’m using for formatting:
default_kable <- function(data, caption) {
  knitr::kable(data, digits = 2, caption = caption, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, align = "l", threeparttable = TRUE, centering = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left", latex_options = c("hold_position", "repeat_header", "longtable"))
}

Here's an example of how I call the function:
default_kable(df, "Participants where the interview date is not the same between phenotyping and consent project")

Output:

I’m using this function to format tables throughout my document, but the table headings are not aligning consistently. I want all of them to start from the left-hand margin where the table begins, but they are currently appearing in different positions. I’m open to completely changing the approach if there’s a more efficient method to generate well-formatted tables in PDF output.
For demonstration purposes, you can use the mtcars or iris datasets or any other public dataset. Any advice on how to achieve consistent table headings or a better approach for formatting tables in PDF output would be greatly appreciated.

It may have more to do with what you're doing in between calling your table. Are you using themes? Styles? Other structural elements? What R chunk options have you assigned--- or rather are they the same options? Have you set any knitr default options? Are your tables combined with other things in their chunks? Does it differ?

I like to remind people too, that to keep a lot of HTML style formatting, you can create your document as output: html_document use the HTML tables, and then print the HTML document to PDF from a browser to get nice formatted PDF document, using Kable package. I have a lot better luck with HTML than latex personally.

There is nothing with knitr::kable, neither kableExtra::kable_styling, there is no build in function for caption alignment and default is centered. But you can achieve it in LaTeX (which is used for PDF creation) adding options in YAML for {caption} package like:
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf

header-includes:
  - \usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

include-before-body:
  text: "\\captionsetup{format=plain, justification=raggedright, skip=0pt}"


And then your function:
#| label: tbl
#| echo: false

default_kable <- function(data, caption) {
  knitr::kable(data, digits = 2, caption = caption, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, align = "l", threeparttable = TRUE, centering = FALSE) |>
    kableExtra::kable_styling(full_width = FALSE, position = "left", latex_options = c("hold_position", "repeat_header", "longtable"))
}

data("iris")

default_kable(head(iris), "Participants where the interview date ...")


gives

or

More options in package documentation: https://ctan.gust.org.pl/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf
